# How to enumerate task requests in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I'm looking to enumerate task requests that users have received in their inbox. I thought I had the right approach, look in the inbox folder and then check for where the message class is equal to IPM.taskrequest, but that's now working. Here's my code, any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Private Sub GetTaskRequests(objApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = _
            objNS.GetDefaultFolder( _
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

        Dim searchCriteria As String = "[MessageClass] = 'IPM.TaskRequest'"
        Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim taskItem As Outlook._TaskRequestItem = Nothing
        Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
        Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
        Dim TTDcounter As Integer = 0
        Try
            folderItems = folder.Items
            folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
            If (folderItems.Count > 0) Then
                resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
                If Not IsNothing(resultItem) Then
                    strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
                    Do
                        If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._TaskRequestItem) Then
                            counter += 1
                            taskItem = resultItem
                            If Not (taskItem.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskComplete) Then
                                strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                " Subject: " + taskItem.Subject + _
                                " Percent Complete: " + taskItem.PercentComplete.ToString() + _
                                " Body: " + taskItem.DueDate)

                                If taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
                                    TTDcounter += 1
                                    Dim listarray() As String = {taskItem.Delegator, taskItem.Subject, taskItem.DueDate, stripEstComp(taskItem.Body.ToString())}
                                    taskPaneControl3.ListView1.Items.Add(TTDcounter).SubItems.AddRange(listarray)
                                End If

                            End If
                        End If
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem)
                        resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
                    Loop Until IsNothing(resultItem)
                End If
            End If
            If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                                   folder.Name + " folder.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
        End Try
    End Sub
```